# Is mysql.format in nodejs MYSQL safe from unescaped input?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I've hear that preparing MySQL queries prevents injection. I'm working with nodejs, so I've found [MySql Preparing Queries](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#preparing-queries). According to the documentation,

> You can use mysql.format to prepare a query with multiple insertion
>   points, utilizing the proper escaping for ids and values.

Does that mean that I can put unescaped things in `userId` and get an escaped mysql request called `sql`?

The code is:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?? = ?";
var inserts = ['users', 'id', userId];
sql = mysql.format(sql, inserts);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe.

Escaping is performed by the [sqlstring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlstring) module, you can take a look at its source code for additional info, it's rather small.

You should always escape your values, either by using the `?` placeholders or calling `escape` directly. However using the placeholders is more recommended because it protects you from scenarios where you might forget to do the manual escaping.